# Python: How do I remove elements from a dictionary and return it as a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been trying an exercise that requires me to remove words in a dictionary containing words that are 7 or fewer characters long. So far I have tried using the `.values()` method to get only the words within the square brackets, and thus create a list to store these words. However, I am having a problem with using the pop method where I get

> "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".

Here is my code :

```
word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
             'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack']}

def main():
    edited_synonyms = remove_word(word_dict)
    print(edited_synonyms)

def remove_word(word_dict):
    synonyms_list = word_dict.values()
    new_list = []
    for i in synonyms_list:
        new_list.extend(i)

    for word in new_list:
        letter_length = len(word)
        if letter_length <= 7:
            new_list.pop(word)

    return new_list

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is right. Any ways you need to add `index` value in `pop`.

**Modified code:**

```
>>> def remove_word(word_dict):
    synonyms_list = word_dict.values()
    new_list = []
    for i in synonyms_list:
        new_list.extend(i)

    for word in new_list:
        letter_length = len(word)
        if letter_length <= 7:
            new_list.pop(new_list.index(word)) # Modified line

    return new_list
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> main()
['exhibit', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose', 'unhurried', 'leisurely', 'behind', 'slack']
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.pop` takes as an argument the index of the item you want to pop from the list, but when you do `new_list.pop(word)`, you are actually providing the item itself, hence the error.

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.pop([i])
>   Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. 
>   You can easily solve this using dictionary comprehension, where you only include values in your list, with length > 7

To fix this, just find the index of the word you want to pop via `list.remove()`

So the line

```
 new_list.pop(word)
```

will change to

```
 new_list.remove(word)
```

But a better approach might be to use a list comprehension like so

```
word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
             'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack']}

#Iterate through the values of the list and pick one with length > 7
res = [v for value in word_dict.values() for v in value if len(v) > 7  ]
print(res)
```

The output will be

```
['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose', 'unhurried', 'leisurely']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
outp = {k: [v for v in word_dict[k] if len(v)<=7 ]for k in word_dict}
```

**Output** :

```
{'show': ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'], 'slow': ['unhurried', 'leisurely']}
```

Answer (score 1):

On a `list` you can pop elements based on the index.

```
word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
             'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack']}

def main():
    edited_synonyms = remove_word(word_dict)
    print(edited_synonyms)

def remove_word(word_dict):
    synonyms_list = word_dict.values()
    new_list = list()
    for i in synonyms_list:
        new_list.extend([word for word in i if len(word) > 7])
    return new_list

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would do it like this:

```
for key in word_dict.keys():
    word_dict[key] = [x for x in word_dict[key] if len(x)>7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the remove property of list in the below way:-

```
for word in new_list:
    print(word)
    letter_length = len(word)
    if letter_length <= 7:
        new_list.remove(word)
```

Alternate way:-

```
print(new_list)
for word in new_list:
    print(word)
    letter_length = len(word)
    if letter_length <= 7:
        new_list.pop(new_list.index(word))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `remove` function instead of `pop`

The `remove()` function takes a single element as an argument.

The `pop()` function takes a single argument (index) and removes the item present at that index.

More details :

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

```
word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
                 'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack']}


res =[]

for i in word_dict:
    tmp =[j for j in word_dict[i] if len(j)<=7]
    res.extend(tmp)

print(res)

# output ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'gradual', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack']
```