# How can I loop through a dictionary to update it and return it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

In this code any values (synonyms) in the dictionary `word_dict` with 7 or fewer characters are to be removed from the dictionary.

I have managed to remove values with 7 or fewer characters, and initially, I tried creating a new dictionary to store the updated values, but that did not work out and I messed up my code.

Any ideas of how I can edit an existing dictionary values without having to create a new dictionary? I prefer not having to use sets, comprehensions, or one-liners to accomplish this. The expected output is supposed to be like this: (could be in any order)

```
{
    'show' : ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
    'dangerous' : ['hazardous', 'perilous', 'uncertain'],
    'slow' : ['leisurely', 'unhurried'],
}
```

The code I tried using to solve the problem, which mostly lies within the remove_word(word_dict) function.

```
word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
             'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack'],
             'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']}

def main():
    edited_synonyms = remove_word(word_dict)
    print(edited_synonyms) #should print out an edited dictionary

def remove_word(word_dict):
    dictionary = {}

    synonyms_list = word_dict.values()
    new_list = []
    for i in synonyms_list:
        new_list.append(i)

    for word in new_list:
        letter_length = len(word)
        if letter_length <= 7:
            new_list.pop(new_list.index(word))

    return dictionary
```

Comment: Is this the extension of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254228/python-how-do-i-remove-elements-from-a-dictionary-and-return-it-as-a-list

Answer (score 3):

You can just update every list for each key in your dictionary:

```
for key, value in word_dict.items():
    temp = []
    for item in value:
        if len(item) > 7:
            temp.append(item)
    word_dict[key] = temp
```

Edit: actually, you don't have to create a new `temp` list, you can use remove:

```
for key, value in word_dict.items():
    for item in value:
        if len(item) > 7:
            value.remove(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should have specified this earlier, is there any way that I can accomplish this without removing the functions?

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep `remove_word` function in your code? If yes you can just put this code inside a function body. Notice that since a dictionary is mutable, you don't have to return word_dict. The function will modify the dictionary passed to function.

Comment: Yeah, but weird it prints "None" for me.

Comment: yes if you use `edited_synonyms = remove_word(word_dict)` then `edited_synonyms` is none since function does not return anything. Instead, you should type: `print(word_dict)`

Comment: It does not seem to update the dictionary for me if I do that.

Comment: In that case, try to add a retrun statement: `return word_dict`, and then assign value like before: `edited_synonyms = remove_word(word_dict)`. If that won't work, please share your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193924/discussion-between-noneiffy04-and-relandom).

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter out the values from existing list like below.

```
from pprint import pprint

word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
             'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack'],
             'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']}

for k, v in word_dict.items():
    word_dict[k] = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 7, v))

pprint(word_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain'],
 'show': ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
 'slow': ['unhurried', 'leisurely']}
```

Comment: profoundly better solution than the other beginner's solution :) +1

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. You could simply construct a dictionary with the same variable and populate each key's value using list comprehension.

   ```
   from pprint import pprint

   word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
                'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack'],
                'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']}

   for key_word in word_dict:    # loops through each identifier word
       word_dict[key_word] = [   # list comprehensioin
               word
               for word in word_dict[key_word] # fetch the original words list 
               if len(word) > 7  # fetches the list of words of size gt 7
       ]

   pprint(word_dict)
   ```
2. Using pure dictionary comprehension

   ```
   word_dict = {key_word: [word for word in word_dict[key_word] if len(word) > 7] for key_word in word_dict}
   ```

Both of which results in

```
{'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain'],
 'show': ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
 'slow': ['unhurried', 'leisurely']}
```